# Account contact info in mail merge

Tags: fields, merge

Does anyone know how to pull a contact from an account into a mail merge template?  I have merged all the account fields but am having trouble isolating a contact name to include in the mailing. I have tried Account_FullName, Account_FirstName, Account_Contact.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Brooke,
I haven't used Mail Merge Templates for a number of years, but in my previous experience, I found it useful to run the mail merge from the Child record (in this case Contact) and then pull the Parent Record (Account) details in.